# Pass CLA of a String into a Docker Image - Python

Tags: python, docker, command-line, argparse

I am wanting to pass a string into the command line arguments that will set the class within a python file when starting up a docker container. I am using the base image of python:3.9.

How do i pass a CLA of a string when building the docker container

Python Script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Pass the variable needed')
    parser.add_argument('var', type=str, help='variable')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ENVPath = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

    if sys.argv[1] == 'prod':
        currentvar = TestPrerequisiteService(ENVPath, prod)

    elif sys.argv[1] == 'test':
        currentvar = TestPrerequisiteService(ENVPath, test)
    else:
        print("Invalid variable")
        exit()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

ADD /app/main.py .
ADD /app/Connect.py .

# Install Chrome WebDriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install Google Chrome
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /microservices

COPY ./app ./app


CMD ["python","./app/main.py"]
```

Some help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the current output when you run the docker container?

Comment: @belfner when i run this command "docker run -p 5000:5000 microservicestesting prod" i get this error Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "prod": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: What is 'prod' ?

Comment: the string variable that i am trying to pass as a CLA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD defines the arguments passed to the ENTRYPOINT of the container. I believe the current ENTRYPOINT of your container is `/bin/sh` which takes `["python","./app/main.py"]` as arguments. When you run the container with `docker run -p 5000:5000 microservicestesting prod`, `prod` overwrites the arguments defined in the dockerfile with CMD.

To get the functionality you want change CMD to ENTRYPOINT, then when you run the docker run command `prod` will be passed as an argument to `["python","./app/main.py"]`